# Push notifications from c# backend through Azure are sent using GCM and not FCM

Tags: azure, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created an app in Xamarin.Forms (Android + iOS) I want to send push notifications to.

My goal is to send single notifications from a backend c# desktop application, and have my notifications pushed to both Android and iOS devices.

To do this I'm going to use Azure Notification Hubs.

In the first stage I'm focusing on pushing notificatins to Android devices, so I followed these steps:

- I created a Firebase account and registered my application.
- I added code to receive notifications in my app.
- I created an Azure account.
- I created a Notification Hub in Azure.
- I inserted my server key in GCM/FCM settings.
- I created my backend.

Backend code:

```
private async void Send()
{

    var msg = "Test message " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    var url = "http://www.google.com";

    string notificationHubName = "MyNotificationHub";
    string notificationHubConnection = "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxx";

    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName);

    Dictionary<string, string> templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    templateParams["messageParam"] = msg;
    templateParams["urlParam"] = url;

    try
    {
        var result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams);
        MessageBox.Show(this, "OK.", "Test message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Exception: " + ex.Message + "." , "Test Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

This code is working and notifications are pushed to my Android devices.

Unfortunately, it seems that Azure still uses GCM instead of FCM to deliver notifications.

I received the following mail from Google:

> Final reminder: Upgrade GCM to Firebase Cloud Messaging by May 29
>
> Hi Roberto, You are receiving this message because you are an owner of a Firebase project that sent a message via the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) endpoint in the last 28 days. Last year we announced that the GCM server and client APIs are deprecated. To prevent a disruption in your service, you must redirect your Cloud Messaging server requests to the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) endpoint at fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/ before May 29, 2019.
>
> We also recommend that you upgrade your client SDKs from GCM to the latest version of Firebase Cloud Messaging. Although existing app installations that use GCM methods will continue to function, GCM methods will not work when your app targets future Android versions (after Android Q).
>
> What do I need to do?
>
> The project listed below has used GCM in the past month. To continue sending messages for this project, update server endpoints and upgrade any apps associated with this project to the FCM SDK. In some cases, the endpoints below may be hostnames that were previously deprecated. However, you should still migrate away from them by May 29, 2019.
>
> • GXXXXXXXXXApp (gXXXXXXXXXapp): about 76 requests to android.googleapis.com in the past 28 days

Moreover, if I try to send a test message from Azure portal, this is the result:

[image: 1]

I'm worried that after May 29 my app will stop receiving notification.

How can I force FCM instead of GCM?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/push-notifications/azure)

Comment: Yes. This is the back-end steps, which I followed:

_Configure the Mobile Apps back end to send push requests by using FCM
In the Azure portal, select Browse All > App Services. Then select your Mobile Apps back end.
Under Settings, select Push. Then select Configure push notification services.
Go to Google (GCM). Enter the FCM legacy server key that you obtained from the Firebase console, and then select Save.
Your service is now configured to work with Firebase Cloud Messaging._